# Getting error there is no entity map defined for the given entities

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I am getting error when trying to open quick create form for 'appointment' for parent entity 'account'. Below is my code which I am trying to implement. Not sure where I am doing wrong:

```
let parent = {};
parent['entityType'] = "account";
parent['id'] = "xxxx";
parent['name'] = "xxx";

var entityFormOptions = {};
entityFormOptions["entityName"] = "appointment";
entityFormOptions["createFromEntity"] = parent;
entityFormOptions["useQuickCreateForm"] = true;
entityFormOptions["openInNewWindow"] = false;

// Open the form.
Xrm.Navigation.openForm(entityFormOptions, params).then(
    function (success) {
            console.log(success);
        },
    function (error) {
                console.log(error);
        });
```

Here is the error as response I am getting:

> {"error":{"code":"0x80040e01","message":"There is no entity map
>   defined for the given entities","innererror":{"message":"There is no
>   entity map defined for the given
>   entities","type":"System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault,
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]","stacktrace":"   at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.Execute(OrganizationRequest
>   request, InvocationContext invocationContext, CallerOriginToken
>   callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType, Boolean checkAdminMode,
>   ExecutionContext executionContext, Dictionary`2
>   optionalParameters)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmODataExecutionContext.Execute(OrganizationRequest
>   request, ExecutionContext executionContext)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmODataServiceDataProvider.ExecuteOperation(CrmODataExecutionContext
>   context, EdmOperation edmOperation, Dictionary`2 parameters,
>   Dictionary`2 boundParameters)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.ActionController.ProcessOperationRequest(String
>   operationName, Dictionary`2 operationParameters, EntityReference
>   entityReference, String boundEntityName, String boundEntityType)\r\n
>
>   at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.ActionController.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<GetUnboundFunction>b__0()\r\n
>   at
>   Microsoft.PowerApps.CoreFramework.ActivityLoggerExtensions.Execute[TResult](ILogger
>   logger, EventId eventId, ActivityType activityType, Func`1 func,
>   IEnumerable`1 additionalCustomProperties)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Telemetry.XrmTelemetryExtensions.Execute[TResult](ILogger
>   logger, XrmTelemetryActivityType activityType, Func`1 func)\r\n   at
>   lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.b__9(Object
>   instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location
>   where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()"}}}

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: added error on the post

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not valid lookup value. Try like that:

```
var lookup = new Array();
lookup[0] = new Object();
lookup[0].id = "xxx";
lookup[0].entityType = "account";
lookup[0].name = "xxx";
//set lookup
entityFormOptions["createFromEntity"] = lookup;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, I have resolved my problem. It seems that the code I have doesn't have parent child relationship as a result it's getting error.